# AngularJS custom filter with exact type

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to filter with selected item in exact type...
I know there is built in filter but it cant solve my problem.. i want custom...

At first see my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

    <select>
        <option value="RICH">Rich</option>
        <option value="POOR">POOR</option>
        <option value="EXTREM POOR">EXTREM POOR</option>
        <option value="VERY POOR">VERY POOR</option>
        <option value="VERY RICH">VERY RICH</option>
      </select> 


<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filterType">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.country}}</td>
    <td>{{x.type}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('filterType', function() {
    return function (item) {
        if (item == undefined) {
            item = [];
        }
        return item.sort((a,b) => a.type.localeCompare(b.type))
    };
});
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden', type: 'POOR'},
    {name:'Margareth',country:'England', type: 'EXTREM POOR'},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Norway', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark', type: 'VERY POOR'},
    {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden', type: 'VERY POOR'},
    {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark', type: 'VERY RICH'},
    {name:'Mary',country:'England', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Norway', type: 'POOR'}
    ];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When want when i select `rich` it should show only rich type.. and when i select `very poor`, it should show me only very poor type.. How can i get it done? i tried a lot but i failed...

Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-model` on `select` element to store the currently selected option. Then you can pass it as an argument to the filter as `x in names | filterType:selected` and filter all the items by the selected type:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

    <select ng-model="selected">
        <option value="RICH">Rich</option>
        <option value="POOR">POOR</option>
        <option value="EXTREM POOR">EXTREM POOR</option>
        <option value="VERY POOR">VERY POOR</option>
        <option value="VERY RICH">VERY RICH</option>
      </select> 


<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names | filterType:selected">
    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
    <td>{{x.country}}</td>
    <td>{{x.type}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('filterType', function() {
    return function (items, selectedType) {
        return items.filter(function(item) {
            return item.type === selectedType
        })
    };
});
app.controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selected = 'RICH';
    $scope.names = [
    {name:'Jani',country:'Norway', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden', type: 'POOR'},
    {name:'Margareth',country:'England', type: 'EXTREM POOR'},
    {name:'Hege',country:'Norway', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark', type: 'VERY POOR'},
    {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden', type: 'VERY POOR'},
    {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark', type: 'VERY RICH'},
    {name:'Mary',country:'England', type: 'RICH'},
    {name:'Kai',country:'Norway', type: 'POOR'}
    ];
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```